# Using Resourcebundle Properties in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, special-characters, resourcebundle

I work on a Java EE web application that uses a combination of Dojo and plain javascript for the front-end.

We've discovered that when ResourceBundle properties are used in javascript, in some cases they end up breaking code.
Specifically, this happens when the properties contain quotes (single and double) & escape sequences (\n, \s ...).

The solution seems to be to include extra escape characters. For instance, \n needs to be prepended by one more slash (\\n) when used in a Js alert 
to correctly render the line break, and Quotes if not escaped truncate the content prematurely for obvious reasons.

Our solution to the above issues so far has been to put in the extra escape characters in the property files itself. But this is something that we would like to move away from.
It seems like this might be a widespread problem and I'd like to hear from the experts on how you might have solved this problem.

Current Usage: `key=A newline is represented with \\n and this \" is within quotes \".`

Envisioned Usage : `key=A newline is represented with \n and this " is within quotes ".`

PS: We typically use the `<fmt:message>` tag to access these values in the front end and for use in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using StringUtils. If has a method to escape input like yours.

[http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks asgoth, I think we are gravitating towards this approach.